# Knockout binding css class to an observed model property

Tags: knockout.js

I want to bind a divs css class to a property of the view model like this:

```
<div id="statusIndicator" data-bind="css: selectedPriority">
```

But this generates the result:

```
 <div id="statusIndicator" class=" 0 1 2 3">
```

This is the view model:

```
myViewModel = {
    selectedPriority: ko.observable('High'),
    Company: ko.observable("Bert"),
    Rows: ko.observableArray([
         new row(),
         new row(),
         new row()
    ]),
    Tabs: ['High', 'Medium', 'Low'],

    selectPriority: function (tab) {
        this.selectedPriority(tab);
    }
};
```

So when i load the page that uses this view model i want the div to be:

```
<div id="statusIndicator" class="High">
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: As I noted in RPNiemeyer's answer It looks like these kinds of dynamic class bindings are now supported in Knockout 2.2.0.  I was having this problem in 2.1.x, and updated to 2.2.0, and it works now.

Comment: @ChrisJaynes you should have made this comment an answer. Takes a while to notice it as a comment.

Comment: @CoderDennis - had the same problem as you described, so I've added an answer about knockout 2.2.0.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For this situation you can do:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'class': selectedPriority}">
```

The only downside to this method is that it will set the class directly rather than toggle a class on or off, so if you are using multiple classes, then `selectedPriority` would need to contain the complete list of classes.

Comment: Is this still the way to do this in Knockout 2.0?

Comment: Yes, it is still the same in 2.0.  There is an example of a binding that would toggle a class on and off (rather than completing replacing the class attribute) here: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---class.

Comment: Thanks RP, that's what I was really looking for.  I knew about the attr binding but was hoping there was one for just the "class" attribute, and the one in your link handles it just the way I wanted it to.  

Also, I did try the attr binding, and it worked on everything except the iPad.  I found a Safari-specific knockout issue about it (https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/233) and tried the workarounds with quotes, but wasn't able to make it work.  With Steve's custom binding, though, it worked great!

Comment: It looks like these kinds of bindings are now supported in Knockout 2.2.0.  I was having this problem in 2.1.x, and updated to 2.2.0, and it works now.

Comment: Somewhat relevant: make sure you use the single quotes around classes that contain special characters. (i.e.: 'my-class' instead of my-class)

Comment: They should really put that in their css binding doc. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you can't set a class directly from your model: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

You can't do something like this:

```
 <div data-bind="css: { high: selectedPriority() == 1, medium: selectedPriority() == 2}">
```

Answer (score 4):

As hinted at in comments by @Chris Jaynes, [Knockout 2.2.0](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/10/29/knockout-2-2-0-released/) makes setting class names easy, as detailed in a blog post by Knockout author Steve Sanderson.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/10/29/knockout-2-2-0-released/

As per the post:

> We’ve also made some features work more like you might always have
>   thought they should work. For example, the css binding can now attach
>   programmatically-generated CSS class names to elements (previously, it
>   was limited to toggling predefined CSS class names)

The blog post also includes a jsfiddle you can play with to see the binding in action. 
http://jsfiddle.net/qRmfH/light/

Note the `css` binding syntax in his example, `css: chosenTicketCss`, which is a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) that returns a css class name:

```
<p data-bind="visible: chosenTicket, css: chosenTicketCss">
    Excellent choice! Suits you perfectly.
</p>
```

Comment: Just spent half a day trying to figure out why my code that perfectly followed the documentation didn't work. Turned out we were still on 2.1 and the css binding has changed between 2.1 and 2.2. Thanks for leading me in the right direction to figure out wtf was going on.